How to Install Tailwind CSS on Svelte Native Mobile App?
I’m working on a Svelte Native mobile application based on svelte-native. My goal is to use Tailwind CSS in the project for styling.
I referred to the official Tailwind CSS installation guide:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation
However, since Svelte Native operates differently from regular web projects, I’m unsure how to configure Tailwind correctly.
My Project Structure:
Here’s the structure of my project (see screenshot):

What I’ve Tried:

Installed Tailwind CSS via npm:

npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init


Tried configuring tailwind.config.js to scan my .svelte files.
Added Tailwind to my CSS file (app.css):

@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

webpack.config.js
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");

module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);

    // Learn how to customize:
    // https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack

    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};

Unfortunately, it doesn’t seem to apply Tailwind styles properly in my components.
My Questions:

Is Tailwind CSS fully compatible with Svelte Native?
How should I configure webpack, postcss, or other build tools (if needed) to make Tailwind work with Svelte Native?
Are there any extra steps or limitations I should be aware of when using Tailwind in a native mobile environment with Svelte?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated! Thanks!

npm install --save @nativescript/tailwind tailwindcss

You've missed @nativescript/tailwind package
Also update tailwind.config.js to
 const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

   /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{css,xml,html,vue,svelte,ts,tsx}'
  ],
  // use the .ns-dark class to control dark mode (applied by NativeScript) - since 'media' (default) is not supported.
  darkMode: ['class', '.ns-dark'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    /**
     * A simple inline plugin that adds the ios: and android: variants
     *
     * Example usage:
     *
     *   <Label class="android:text-red-500 ios:text-blue-500" />
     *
     */
    plugin(function ({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('android', '.ns-android &');
      addVariant('ios', '.ns-ios &');
    }),
  ],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false // disables browser-specific resets
  }
}

as is recommended officially here
